# How do I extend the renderer to add the path of a template into the html the templates rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have many .erb files on this project that I am working on, and to make it easy to debug from the browser i would like the path of each template file to be hidden in the source (for development only) like so `<!-- BEGIN /path/to/file -->` and `<!-- END /path/to/file -->`

How do you change `render` so that It prepends every render with the path of the template that it is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the gist that i am using for this:

https://gist.github.com/1386152

and for rails 2

https://gist.github.com/905286

Comment: wow, thanks. this is just what I need. I was thinking of creating a gem for something like this, but it's so concise.